# General Campaign Measurement is not passing Campaign data in Intent if app open from PlayStore

Tags: android

I have Campaign URL which redirect to PlayStore to Install OR Open the App.

If App already Installed , PlayStore show "Open" button to Open the App.
Once App open it should pass the Campaign data through Intent for launched Activity. But Intent.getData() does not contain the Campaign data.

```
In onCreate(){
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        String content = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
}
```

But both uri and content is null, if app launched from Playstore using "Open".

Any other solution to read the Campaign data if app open from PlayStore.